# Deploying an existing .NET project to Bluemix

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, ibm-cloud

I want to deploy my .NET application to the Bluemix platform.

Can any one tell me what are the necessary steps for it? I am using SVN as repository.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: Bluemix now includes a runtime for ASP.NET 5. In the Dashboard, it appears in the list when you create a web app, and appears in the catalog in the list of runtimes (currently on the Labs page).

For more info:

- Docs: [Creating apps with ASP.NET 5](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/dotnet/index.html)
- Announcement: [We’ve Introduced .NET in Bluemix and Open Sourced the Buildpack](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/05/15/asp-net-5-in-bluemix/)
- Tutorial: [Getting started with ASP.NET 5 in Bluemix](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/05/18/getting-started-asp-net-5-bluemix/)

---

Thank you for your interest in Bluemix. As discussed in "[Deploying .NET Application on Bluemix, connecting to external databases, Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30108830/deploying-net-application-on-bluemix-connecting-to-external-databases-watson)," IBM and Microsoft have announced support for .NET runtimes in Bluemix, but that is not yet available. Stay tuned.

It looks like your question concerns ASP.NET. As discussed in "[Can I run my Tomcat app on Bluemix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807988/can-i-run-my-tomcat-app-on-bluemix/30807141#30807141)" Bluemix includes a buildpack for ASP.NET, `aspnet5-experimental`. It explains how to specify a buildpack when pushing an app to Cloud Foundry. "[Deploying a Standard vNext WebApplication VS Next 2015 RC to Bluemix fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692801/deploying-a-standard-vnext-webapplication-vs-next-2015-rc-to-bluemix-fails)" also has some details about the ASP.NET buildpack.

Comment: Bobby Woolf.....Can you please give the feedback on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36715501/host-app-crash-with-status-127-in-bluemix-server