# Host app crash with status "127" in Bluemix server

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, ibm-cloud

I have created a c# WCF service with framework 3.5. and a Host application which will start the service.Now I have to upload this service and Host application into Bluemix server.I have also uploaded it on server by command

```
cf push AppName -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/.net-buildpack
```

But the problem is when I start the service the error occur that :

> an instance of the app crashed: failed to accept connections within
>   health check timeout exit status: 127, CRASHED

All I have checked in local system.Service was running fine.

**EDIT:**

After execute `"cf logs AppName --recent"` command.....

```
2016-04-19T17:24:08.20+0530 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5fc59
aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c", "version"=>"6c71f6d3-923e-4fd3-a448-bed0
4d1c54f4", "instance"=>"fc4664a568404e28b4f915ded6ed321a", "index"=>0, "reason"=
>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connection
s within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461066848}
2016-04-19T17:25:06.13+0530 [DEA/107]    OUT Removing crash for app with id 5fc5
9aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:25:06.13+0530 [DEA/107]    OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:25:06.13+0530 [DEA/107]    OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:27:18.44+0530 [DEA/116]    OUT Removing crash for app with id 5fc5
9aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:27:18.44+0530 [DEA/116]    OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:27:18.44+0530 [DEA/116]    OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:28:11.78+0530 [DEA/64]     OUT Removing crash for app with id 5fc5
9aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:28:11.78+0530 [DEA/64]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:28:11.78+0530 [DEA/64]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:29:18.87+0530 [DEA/7]      OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:31:40.49+0530 [DEA/48]     OUT Removing crash for app with id 5fc5
9aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:31:40.50+0530 [DEA/48]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:31:40.50+0530 [DEA/48]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:32:40.84+0530 [DEA/56]     OUT Removing crash for app with id 5fc5
9aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:32:40.84+0530 [DEA/56]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:32:40.84+0530 [DEA/56]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:33:52.68+0530 [DEA/30]     OUT Removing crash for app with id 5fc5
9aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:33:52.69+0530 [DEA/30]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:33:52.69+0530 [DEA/30]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:34:41.32+0530 [DEA/12]     OUT Removing crash for app with id 5fc5
9aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:34:41.32+0530 [DEA/12]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:34:41.32+0530 [DEA/12]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:36:36.79+0530 [DEA/20]     OUT Removing crash for app with id 5fc5
9aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:36:36.79+0530 [DEA/20]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:36:36.79+0530 [DEA/20]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:40:21.45+0530 [DEA/40]     OUT Removing crash for app with id 5fc5
9aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:40:21.45+0530 [DEA/40]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:40:21.45+0530 [DEA/40]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:43:47.21+0530 [DEA/96]     OUT Removing crash for app with id 5fc5
9aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:43:47.21+0530 [DEA/96]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:43:47.21+0530 [DEA/96]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:49:01.57+0530 [DEA/53]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:49:13.64+0530 [DEA/53]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start
accepting connections
2016-04-19T17:49:13.67+0530 [API/5]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5fc59
aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c", "version"=>"6c71f6d3-923e-4fd3-a448-bed0
4d1c54f4", "instance"=>"706e6c77f4b74b5cb5c4356e05f5f519", "index"=>0, "reason"=
>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connection
s within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461068353}
2016-04-19T17:49:13.68+0530 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5fc59
aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c", "version"=>"6c71f6d3-923e-4fd3-a448-bed0
4d1c54f4", "instance"=>"706e6c77f4b74b5cb5c4356e05f5f519", "index"=>0, "reason"=
>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connection
s within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461068353}
2016-04-19T17:50:52.88+0530 [DEA/10]     OUT Removing crash for app with id 5fc5
9aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:50:52.88+0530 [DEA/10]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T17:50:52.88+0530 [DEA/10]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:00:19.42+0530 [DEA/26]     OUT Removing crash for app with id 5fc5
9aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:00:19.42+0530 [DEA/26]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:00:19.42+0530 [DEA/26]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:01:19.26+0530 [API/3]      OUT Updated app with guid 5fc59aea-d49f
-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c ({"state"=>"STOPPED"})
2016-04-19T18:01:21.86+0530 [API/0]      OUT Updated app with guid 5fc59aea-d49f
-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
2016-04-19T18:01:21.87+0530 [DEA/156]    OUT Starting app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:01:36.65+0530 [DEA/49]     OUT Removing crash for app with id 5fc5
9aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:01:36.65+0530 [DEA/49]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:01:36.65+0530 [DEA/49]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:01:40.10+0530 [DEA/156]    ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start
accepting connections
2016-04-19T18:01:40.15+0530 [API/8]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5fc59
aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c", "version"=>"bab7fca5-2947-42ad-b17a-579b
547e2f57", "instance"=>"5f0365c236984249a85398c3b52bf15c", "index"=>0, "reason"=
>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connection
s within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461069100}
2016-04-19T18:01:40.15+0530 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5fc59
aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c", "version"=>"bab7fca5-2947-42ad-b17a-579b
547e2f57", "instance"=>"5f0365c236984249a85398c3b52bf15c", "index"=>0, "reason"=
>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connection
s within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461069100}
2016-04-19T18:02:16.58+0530 [DEA/33]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:02:29.88+0530 [DEA/33]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start
accepting connections
2016-04-19T18:02:29.93+0530 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5fc59
aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c", "version"=>"bab7fca5-2947-42ad-b17a-579b
547e2f57", "instance"=>"e6c005e9a7b04499b6a93b36bc40626f", "index"=>0, "reason"=
>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connection
s within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461069149}
2016-04-19T18:02:29.93+0530 [API/7]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5fc59
aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c", "version"=>"bab7fca5-2947-42ad-b17a-579b
547e2f57", "instance"=>"e6c005e9a7b04499b6a93b36bc40626f", "index"=>0, "reason"=
>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connection
s within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461069149}
2016-04-19T18:02:34.27+0530 [DEA/136]    OUT Removing crash for app with id 5fc5
9aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:02:34.27+0530 [DEA/136]    OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:02:34.27+0530 [DEA/136]    OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:03:31.82+0530 [DEA/85]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:03:38.05+0530 [DEA/85]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start
accepting connections
2016-04-19T18:03:38.06+0530 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5fc59
aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c", "version"=>"bab7fca5-2947-42ad-b17a-579b
547e2f57", "instance"=>"d5e3bf2c626a4a1fa614b0340b8af4d2", "index"=>0, "reason"=
>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connection
s within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461069218}
2016-04-19T18:03:38.06+0530 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5fc59
aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c", "version"=>"bab7fca5-2947-42ad-b17a-579b
547e2f57", "instance"=>"d5e3bf2c626a4a1fa614b0340b8af4d2", "index"=>0, "reason"=
>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connection
s within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461069218}
2016-04-19T18:03:41.27+0530 [DEA/73]     OUT Removing crash for app with id 5fc5
9aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:03:41.27+0530 [DEA/73]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:03:41.27+0530 [DEA/73]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:04:46.35+0530 [DEA/105]    OUT Starting app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:04:48.43+0530 [DEA/185]    OUT Removing crash for app with id 5fc5
9aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:04:48.43+0530 [DEA/185]    OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:04:48.43+0530 [DEA/185]    OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:04:58.66+0530 [API/7]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5fc59
aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c", "version"=>"bab7fca5-2947-42ad-b17a-579b
547e2f57", "instance"=>"9c6507a3e3ac456fb7877cbdaeac0dee", "index"=>0, "reason"=
>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"app instance exited", "cras
h_timestamp"=>1461069298}
2016-04-19T18:05:58.62+0530 [DEA/105]    ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start
accepting connections
2016-04-19T18:05:58.68+0530 [API/2]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5fc59
aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c", "version"=>"bab7fca5-2947-42ad-b17a-579b
547e2f57", "instance"=>"9c6507a3e3ac456fb7877cbdaeac0dee", "index"=>0, "reason"=
>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connection
s within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461069358}
2016-04-19T18:06:31.77+0530 [DEA/118]    OUT Starting app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:06:33.17+0530 [DEA/133]    OUT Removing crash for app with id 5fc5
9aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:06:33.17+0530 [DEA/133]    OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:06:33.17+0530 [DEA/133]    OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:06:46.66+0530 [DEA/118]    ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start
accepting connections
2016-04-19T18:06:46.69+0530 [API/2]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5fc59
aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c", "version"=>"bab7fca5-2947-42ad-b17a-579b
547e2f57", "instance"=>"d77cdb7961bd4b34aa8db472ae237c7b", "index"=>0, "reason"=
>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connection
s within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461069406}
2016-04-19T18:06:46.73+0530 [API/8]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5fc59
aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c", "version"=>"bab7fca5-2947-42ad-b17a-579b
547e2f57", "instance"=>"d77cdb7961bd4b34aa8db472ae237c7b", "index"=>0, "reason"=
>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connection
s within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461069406}
2016-04-19T18:09:19.14+0530 [DEA/107]    OUT Starting app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:09:20.64+0530 [DEA/67]     OUT Removing crash for app with id 5fc5
9aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:09:20.64+0530 [DEA/67]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:09:20.64+0530 [DEA/67]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:09:30.29+0530 [DEA/107]    ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start
accepting connections
2016-04-19T18:09:30.31+0530 [API/5]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5fc59
aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c", "version"=>"bab7fca5-2947-42ad-b17a-579b
547e2f57", "instance"=>"ec4024c1ec3d432bbb93be467fcfb5b0", "index"=>0, "reason"=
>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connection
s within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461069570}
2016-04-19T18:09:30.34+0530 [API/7]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5fc59
aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c", "version"=>"bab7fca5-2947-42ad-b17a-579b
547e2f57", "instance"=>"ec4024c1ec3d432bbb93be467fcfb5b0", "index"=>0, "reason"=
>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connection
s within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461069570}
2016-04-19T18:13:20.69+0530 [DEA/53]     OUT Removing crash for app with id 5fc5
9aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:13:20.69+0530 [DEA/53]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:13:20.69+0530 [DEA/53]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:13:31.84+0530 [DEA/25]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:13:45.93+0530 [DEA/25]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start
accepting connections
2016-04-19T18:13:45.96+0530 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5fc59
aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c", "version"=>"bab7fca5-2947-42ad-b17a-579b
547e2f57", "instance"=>"cf3c145421a34b95896610bc89646fd7", "index"=>0, "reason"=
>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connection
s within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461069825}
2016-04-19T18:13:46.03+0530 [API/6]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5fc59
aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c", "version"=>"bab7fca5-2947-42ad-b17a-579b
547e2f57", "instance"=>"cf3c145421a34b95896610bc89646fd7", "index"=>0, "reason"=
>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connection
s within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461069825}
2016-04-19T18:20:29.44+0530 [DEA/35]     OUT Removing crash for app with id 5fc5
9aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:20:29.44+0530 [DEA/35]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:20:29.44+0530 [DEA/35]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:20:46.47+0530 [DEA/95]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:21:01.55+0530 [DEA/95]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start
accepting connections
2016-04-19T18:21:01.59+0530 [API/4]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5fc59
aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c", "version"=>"bab7fca5-2947-42ad-b17a-579b
547e2f57", "instance"=>"c47d332994214f18ac789bb96cf15749", "index"=>0, "reason"=
>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connection
s within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461070261}
2016-04-19T18:21:01.59+0530 [API/2]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5fc59
aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c", "version"=>"bab7fca5-2947-42ad-b17a-579b
547e2f57", "instance"=>"c47d332994214f18ac789bb96cf15749", "index"=>0, "reason"=
>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connection
s within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461070261}
2016-04-19T18:34:01.88+0530 [DEA/43]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:34:14.25+0530 [API/5]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5fc59
aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c", "version"=>"bab7fca5-2947-42ad-b17a-579b
547e2f57", "instance"=>"1e403df6ffe0400789fdc4911d800206", "index"=>0, "reason"=
>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"app instance exited", "cras
h_timestamp"=>1461071054}
2016-04-19T18:34:47.68+0530 [DEA/6]      OUT Removing crash for app with id 5fc5
9aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:34:47.69+0530 [DEA/6]      OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) wit
h guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:34:47.69+0530 [DEA/6]      OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with
 guid 5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c
2016-04-19T18:35:14.25+0530 [DEA/43]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start
accepting connections
2016-04-19T18:35:14.36+0530 [API/9]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5fc59
aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"5fc59aea-d49f-4c5f-b010-f089ac61e47c", "version"=>"bab7fca5-2947-42ad-b17a-579b
547e2f57", "instance"=>"1e403df6ffe0400789fdc4911d800206", "index"=>0, "reason"=
>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connection
s within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461071114}
```

Comment: Could you please update your question and add output of `cf logs AppName --recent`?

Comment: please check the edit part.

Comment: Even a simple c# application is not starting...

Comment: I couldn't see any obvious errors in the logs, did you try using the Bluemix ASP.NET 5 buildpack? Try run `cf push AppName -b aspnet5-experimental_v0_6-20150916-1220`

Comment: The ASP.Net 5 buildpack is intended to support ASP.Net Core (formerly ASP.Net 5) applications, but the OP is trying to push an application which is targetting .Net Framework 3.5.

Comment: Yes @DanielGrim...you right.It is actually console app...which starts a WCF service.So I don't think ASP.NET 5 buildpack would work here..